# Sidebar Transparente

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Estoy a vueltas con una plantilla de **Wordpress** llamada **Uncode** de la empresa **Envato**. Su foro de soporte está muy bien, pero no me dan solución para lo siguiente:

La plantilla posee un menú que se puede poner en horizontal en el top de la pagina o como sidebar. Yo lo he puesto como y mi intención es que se vea transparente para que el slider que tengo en la pantalla de inicio se vea a pantalla completa pero con el menú visible al mismo tiempo.

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

He intentado hacerlo variando la opacidad del menú, he intentado dándole el valor `transparent` e incluso tocando los RGBs pero no soy capaz de hacerlo. También he intentado hacerlo por el mismo método que tiene la plantilla **Skylab**  que sí permite hacerlo y que además genera un degradado para que la imagen se integre por debajo, pero con los mismo parámetros no soy capaz de hacerlo.

Comment: El menú al que te refieres es el que tiene las clases `isotope-filters menu-container` etc?

Comment: Si exacto, ese es el menú. He leido abajo una respuesta que voy a ver si funciona, pero si tienes alguna sugerencia será más que bienvenida.

Comment: La clase que le pone el color es `.style-color-194709-bg`. Si setas su propiedad `background: transparent` funciona. A las malas yo le pondría `!important` y a correr. La solución que sugiere @Marc Lemien está bien, pero la veo mas como última opción.

Comment: Es buena respuesta @eledgaar ponlo como respuesta no como comentario, para que una u otra opción pueda recibir votos y el visto bueno.

Comment: No encuentro por ningun lado el .style-color-194709-bg que me dices, sera que tengo la cabeza ya embotada, en que css esta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La clase que le pone el color del menú es `.style-color-194709-bg`, si setéas su propiedad `background: transparent` funciona.

A las malas yo le pondría `!important` y a correr. La solución que sugiere @Marc Lemien está bien, pero la veo mas como última opción. He de confesar que ese 'apaño' yo también lo he utilizado bastante pero siempre como última opción.

Si ves que no das con esa clase una buena opción es que le añadas tú mismo una personalizada y manejes como quieras sus propiedades.

Comment: Esta opción es más profesional esta claro y mejor incluso por el tema del responsive.

Comment: No encuentro por ningun lado el .style-color-194709-bg que me dices, sera que tengo la cabeza ya embotada, en que css esta?

Comment: Por eso uso la opción que te comenté, porque en wordpress antes no encuentras donde esta especificado algo, sino sabes mucho de wordpress es un lío. Lo mío es lo más rápido.

Comment: No he visto tu hoja de estilos, lo he inspeccionado desde el inspector de **Chrome**. En cualquier caso siempre puedes añadir tu propia clase y definir las propiedades que necesites. @Mark Lemien te tengo que dar toda la razón, este tipo de tareas se pueden volver complejas cuando se trabaja con **Wordpress**.

Comment: He probado a hacerlo con mi propia clase y ha funcionado!!! El oraculo de Delfos se queda en pañales con la gente de aquí.

Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Genial! Encantado de haberte sido de ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro que hayas dado con la solución! =)

Comment: Gracias a vosotros, os debo una birra si pasais por Sevilla ;)

Comment: Pues macho, yo soy de Madrid pero vivo en Sevilla hace poco y la verdad es que no conozco a casi nadie... ¿Cuando esa birra?

Comment: te dejo aqui mi correo y te paso por ahi el mvoil pa quedar pa ese cervezon!!! pinedux@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

**Opción 1:**
Hacerlo a tu gusto no es un pijada, yo también personalizo mucho las plantillas. En teoría si buscas las imágenes y las conviertes en transparente y las guardas en `png` debería ser suficiente. Si no hay imagen a editar y es un degradado con código, deberás borrar el código y decirle que es una imagen y posteriormente poner la tuya transparente, notificando al código que es un `png`.

**Opción 2:**
Yo tengo cuenta en **Envato** desde hace años, te sugiero que contactes al desarrollador por mensaje privado desde su perfil para hacerle la pregunta de lo que quieres. Si no sabes inglés y quieres que te ayude en formular la pregunta dime tu nombre de usuario de **Envato** y te busco.

**Opción 3:**
Edita directamente desde tu ftp, los archivos referentes al menu, busca el `css`. O pegalo aqui en **SOes** para que te lo podamos editar.

Salu2.

Comment: ¿Te han dicho alguna vez que eres un crack? Lo del .png transparente no se me había ocurrido. Voy a tratar de hacerlo así y si no doy con la solución te posteo por aqui el css.

Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: Me lo han dicho muy pocas veces y siempre amigos así que no cuenta. =) Pero no es de ser un crack, simplemente es lo que siempre hago yo.